# Can't use fetch() to GET JSON but I CAN visit same URL with browser

Tags: javascript, json, cors, fetch, sinatra

**Running very simple server with Sinatra:**

Info:
Sinatra is on `:4567`
React is on `:3000`

```rb
# 'shifts' is a hash

get '/shifts' do
  content_type :json
  shifts.to_json
end
```

**Sinatra** is `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4567`

If I visit this with any browser (FF, Chrome, Safari), I can see the JSON on the page as well as in the Network tab of the dev tools. I can also ping it with `curl` from command line and it responds with a JSON object; I didn't even have to set headers.

[image: Visiting this URL from browser address]

### Problem:

If I use `fetch(...)`, (from React, or from the console of a browser) I initially get a CORS error. I believe I solved it by modifying the `Headers`:

```js
const url = "127.0.0.1:4567";

const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "127.0.0.1:3000"); // (Port on which my React app is running)

const myInit = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: myHeaders,
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "default",
};

// Then I try this:
fetch(`${url}/shifts`, myInit).then((response) => console.log(response));
```

[image: After I think I've solved for CORS]
There is no more CORS error, but I'm not getting any JSON. The result of `...console.log(response)...` the response is:

```js
body: ReadableStream { locked: false }
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {  }
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/127.0.0.1:4567/shifts"
```

The request *type* in the network tab is `html`, but not JSON.

If I try this:

```js
fetch(`${url}/shifts`, myInit) 
    .then((response) => response.json());
```

I get this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

### Theories:

- Is there something I'm not doing correctly on the server side?
- Should I be setting all kinds of `Content-Type` properties in `Headers`? I feel like I've tried that as well.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` seems like the JSON in your backend is not formatted correctly. You might want to check that again and also change the content type to json.

Comment: @sid-c Add `Content-Type` in headers to be `application/json`? I'll give it a go again. On back-end, though, I'm getting a JSON response when I visit that URL from browser but I'll see what else I could be doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse, it might be helpful

Comment: First of all, check what the response is in plain text. Perhaps it's returning something completely different instead of your JSON response.

Comment: Your request uses the url "http://localhost:3000/127.0.0.1:4567/shifts" which is not the location of the json, this is most likely because ```const url = "127.0.0.1:4567";```, try ```const url = "http://127.0.0.1:4567";``` instead

Comment: OK, I corrected the `url` to be `const url = "http://127.0.0.1"`. I'm getting CORS errors again and now the server is showing that this is request coming in: `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2021:15:58:36 -0500] "OPTIONS /shifts HTTP/1.1" 404 468 0.0008` which is different than when I use `curl` or the browser's address bar and it logs a simple `GET` request. Thanks for the tips; I'll keep working on it; I obviously haven't solved the `Headers` issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

## Real issue:

`Sinatra` wasn't allowing CORS. I tried various solutions to massage the server into allowing my request, but got to a point where I couldn't add the `Allow` header to the `OPTIONS` [pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). All the things I tried were:

```rb
options '/shifts' do
  headers "Allow" => "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
  headers "Allow" => "*"
  headers "Access-Control-Request-Method" => "GET"
  headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "http://localhost:3000"
  content_type :json
end

get '/shifts' do
 headers "Allow" => "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
 headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "http://localhost:3000"
 content_type :json
 shifts.to_json
end
```

What saved the day was this: [sinatra/cross_origin](https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin), which is a gem.

My code looks like this now and I can ping Sinatra server @ `:4567` from React app @ `:3000` and I have my JSON. Thanks to all for your help.

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'

configure do
  enable :cross_origin
end

# Back to a very simple GET handler
get '/shifts' do
  content_type :json
  shifts.to_json
end
```

I'd like to know how to intercept that `OPTIONS` request and add any necessary Headers, but I need to move on for today.